# Como selecionar um elemento do tipo aria-controls

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

[image: aria-controls]

Tenho tentando de todas as formas executar o método Click() do WedDriver no elemento button

```
//*[@id="pedigree-controls"]/div[2]/div/div/button (destacado em azul (dropbtn))
```

No entanto, por alguma razão, talvez por se tratar de um aria-controls e conter um **span class="visually-hidden"** eu não consigo.

Alguém conhece alguma forma de chegar nesse elemento?

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[aria-controls='pedigree_select']")).Clicks();
```

Comment: Não sei sobre o Selenium mas no jQuery não pode ter aspas no pedigree_select. Funcionaria assim:
`$("li[aria-controls=pedigree_select]")` talvez no seu caso isso possa ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver!
Eu conseguia encontrar o elemento mas não executar nenhuma ação nele (click por exemplo). Isso estava acontecendo porque a página foi construída com Polymer e consequentemente tive que tratar as divs por camada até chegar no elemento.